# iPhone call from app in Swift Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift

I checked and tried previous answers on how to make call directly from the app but I keep getting errors. I just made a button in the storryboard and hooked it up to the view controller. It keeps giving me the ERROR Excpected ',' separator but that doesn't solve anything. Do I need to add code to the AppDelegate or anything else? I really would like to know the way to do this in Swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func theCallMeButtonMethod(sender: AnyObject) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt:0123456789"]]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: You've got a bit of objective-C in your swift code there. What's your current swift code look like?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Swift 3**

This code will help you :

```
let phone = "tel://982374234"
let url = URL(string: phone)!
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

OR

```
let url = URL(string: "tel://9809088798")!
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, no more errors but simulator doesn't show the action, is that because it can't make calls?

Comment: yea, simulator can't make calls. It will work fine on real devices

Answer (score 8):

This is how you access the application object and open a URL in swift.

Replace number below:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"telprompt:0123456789"))
```